# UITableViewCell's programmatically set label has default value in unit test

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uilabel, xctest

I'm failing to test my programmatically set label texts against their expected values; the test failure notice always has them at their default values. The values are correct in the actual run of the program, but it's disconcerting that I cannot get the unit tests to pass.

I'm setting up my unit test as follows:

```
class StopTableViewControllerTest: XCTestCase {
    var sut: StopTableViewController!

    let indexOfCell = 0
    var cellToTest: StopTableViewCell!

    let route = Route(name: "Clark", number: "22")
    // 22 is known to be North-South
    let direction = Direction.Northbound

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        sut = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StopTableViewController") as! StopTableViewController
        sut.route = route
        sut.direction = direction
        sut.loadView()
        sleep(1)
        cellToTest = sut.tableView(sut.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: indexOfCell, section: 0)) as! StopTableViewCell
    }
    ...
}
```

I have the `sleep(1)` in there to give my code time to make a REST call and populate the data.

As for the cell's label, I'm setting it with both a property observer and a call to the main thread:

```
class StopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    ...
    var stop = BusStop(ID: "Loading…", name: "") {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label.text = self.stop.name
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And this `var stop` is set quite expectedly:

```
class StopTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    ...
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if dataLoaded {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StopCell", for: indexPath) as! StopTableViewCell
            cell.stop = stops[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StopCell", for: indexPath)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As I've said, this comes out fine in the program, but the following test fails.

```
func testStopCells_LabelOfCellMatchesStopName() {
    XCTAssertEqual(cellToTest.stop.name, cellToTest.label.text)
}
```

The failure notice reads `XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("Clark & Addison")") is not equal to ("Optional("Loading…")")`. I'm completely flummoxed, because the selfsame cell in a running instance of the program reads "Clark & Addison".

Comment: Is your REST data loaded? Where this loading data is triggered?

Comment: The REST data is triggered and loaded. The REST call is in `viewDidLoad`. My tests for to check for the data and the debugger show that the data has been populated.